# Change product images WooCommerce (jpeg > webp.) the right way?

Tags: seo, wordpress, ftp, woocommerce, products

I'm working on converting product images from .jpeg to webp, I want to do this without a plugin, but preferably within the functions of WooCommerce. I exported the products as a .csv file and adjusted the image url.

So as a test I modified and reimported a product with an image and its variations in the .csv file which would have changed the products and corresponding media url. It should now be visible in the store.

But I just see a .jpeg extension with the article which should now have a .webp extension. This doesn't seem to work.

I wonder why I don't see any result of this action, does anyone have a suggestion, am I doing something wrong? It just doesn't seem to grab the clutch. And to manually change every product with all variations would take too much time.

Can someone give me some advice?